# How to set blackDays in JQM DateBox

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, datebox

HTML CODE

```
<input name="leaveFrom" id="leaveFrom" type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode":"calbox","afterToday":"true","overrideDateFormat": "%d-%m-%Y"}' />
```

JS Code

i have tried following options

1.

```
var weekEndArray = [0, 6];
$('#leaveFrom').datebox({ "blackDays": weekEndArray });
```

2.

```
var weekEndArray = [0, 6];
$("#leaveFrom").data("option", {"blackDays": weekEndArray});
```

3.

```
var weekEndArray = [0, 6];
$("#leaveFrom").data('datebox').options.blackDays = weekEndArray ;
```

also

```
alert($("#leaveFrom").data('datebox')); alerts as undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are defining DateBox via data-attributes you have to set blackDays too on attribute like:

```
<input name="leaveFrom" id="leaveFrom" type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode":"calbox","afterToday":"true","overrideDateFormat": "%d-%m-%Y", "blackDays": [0,6]}' />
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/L4ye6dxr/

Answer (score 0):

```
var weekEndArray = [0, 6];
$('#leaveFrom').datebox({ "blackDays": weekEndArray });
```

This method is absolutely correct.  Of course, it only works if the option is functional, which at the time you wrote this question it most certainly was not.  It is working now, and the DateBox-4.0 sources have been patched on my server.

Thanks for catching this!

SHA: [9b72649](https://github.com/jtsage/jquery-mobile-datebox/commit/9b726490cfcb7de459e9e35be289aff39957b38c)...